# Cracking an 8-character password

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, passwords, crunch

So here's the situation.

I am locked out of my admin portal on my WiFi home modem+router (Dlink 3782) and the default password has been lost to time on the back of the router and I wanted to have a bit of fun instead of calling my provider about this.

I know the default password is an `a-zA-Z` 8 char (it's random).

So I wanted to use Hydra via Debian Wheezy to crack it but it won't take the parameters to bruteforce with http-get as it generates over 4 billion passwords.

`crunch` wants to generate terabytes worth of data for a wordlist via

```
crunch 8 8 AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz -o passwords.txt
```

I was wondering if there's a way to either pipe the stdout of `crunch` (so I wouldn't have to get 500TB worth storage) to either `hydra` or something that could crack it.

I don't have the password hash either.

Yes, I am performing this on my hardware that only my household uses.

Comment: There are 52^8 = 53,459,728,531,456 different password combinations. Unless you are able to narrow down the password possibilities considerably, this is not something you're going to be able to crack given your current situation.

Comment: Just reset and move on.  Unless you know the character set.  What you want will take days/months/decades

Comment: I thought the factory reset made all router passwords 'admin'

Comment: Use [Routersploit](https://github.com/threat9/routersploit) to try finding any **vulnerability** in your router. If there's not any such, you are not getting any fun out of using cracking tools and better call the provider instead.

Comment: "I thought the factory reset made all router passwords 'admin' " Not any more, they have unique passwords for each router now, its why I take a pic of the password on the router when I get a new one.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not like its urgent, I'm just curious and having a learning experience. The charset is Alphanumeric with both cases of letters and is an 8 length string. I have months and days to waste, I'm just curious. I don't even really care if it would take forever, just looking for explanations n that.

Answer (score 4):

There are easier much more time efficient ways of recovering the administrative access to a router. But if your just doing it for fun, or to see how long it actually would take.

**Piping crunch**

```
crunch 8 8 AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz  | Hydra (enter Hydra specific parameters)
```

When you get to the point in the Hydra command where you need to enter the dictionary file, instead of a filename use "-". It will create and transfer the password strings in memory, no storage needed.

It should be noted, depending on the system resources and how much memory is available, you may be limited to a certain total of characters when crunching from memory.  The numbers specified in "crunch 1 8".